# Как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал и показывал кнопки не всем пользователям чата, а только пользователю, который сделал запрос?

Tags: python, telebot

Тут у меня появилась проблема. Суть в чём, бот отвечает всем пользователям и другие пользователи не могут использовать его. Мне нужно, чтобы срабатывание команды было у каждого пользователя своё.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Дарова, этот бот написан специально для отслеживания всей информации, которая касается нашей группы', reply_markup=markup1)
    
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
    def stop(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Бот остановлен', reply_markup=markup2)
    
    markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    itembtna = types.KeyboardButton('Сайт')
    itembtnv = types.KeyboardButton('Расписание')
    itembtnc = types.KeyboardButton('Информация по всем Учителям')
    itembtnd = types.KeyboardButton('Архив учебников')
    itembtnh = types.KeyboardButton('Домашние задание на семестр')
    markup1.row(itembtna, itembtnv)
    markup1.row(itembtnc, itembtnd, itembtnh)
    
    
    markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    begin = types.KeyboardButton('/start')
    markup2.row(begin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй отправлять не по ID чата, а юзера. message.from.id

```
"update_id": XXXXXXXXXX,
 "message": {
  "message_id": XXXXXXX,
  "from": {
   "id": XXXXXXXXX,
   "is_bot": false,
   "first_name": "Илья",
   "username": "ilya_yalovoy",
   "language_code": "ru"
  },
  "chat": {
   "id": XXXXXXXXXX,
   "first_name": "Илья",
   "username": "ilya_yalovoy",
   "type": "private"
  },
```